# How can i write attributes in model while using entity frame work Database first approch

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm developing an application using asp.net mvc 5 and entity framework 6. I have generated model classes from database and set some attributes to entities in model class. But these attributes are gets cleared each time I refresh the entity model. I know this is because the model classes are generated from database. Then how can I specify additional attributes in entity frame work db first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a metadata class. Say your model class is `Employee`. You would create a separate partial class file for `Employee` and define the metadata type.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeMetadata))]
public partial class Employee
{
}
```

DO NOT add the above attribute to your generated `Employee.cs`. Create a separate file (e.g. `EmployeePartial.cs`).

Then you would create EmployeeMetadata class and define the attributes you want.

```
public class EmployeeMetadata
{
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```